# IP address spoofing using SharpPcap on C#

Tags: c#, ip-address, spoofing, sharppcap

I will use SharpPcap framework to make my spoofing program, so I need to edit my machine's IP address of the packet with another IP address on the source address field.

I found some example on SharpPcap project, but how can I edit or change the source address field of sending packet?

Here is the sample code for sending random packets:

```
byte[] bytes = GetRandomPacket();

private static byte[] GetRandomPacket()
{
    byte[] packet = new byte[200];
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.NextBytes( packet );
    return packet;
}
```

-
    device.SendPacket( bytes );

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com) instead.

Here is how you build a simple IPv4 packet with specific source and destination addresses and a custom payload in Pcap.Net:

```
Packet packet =
    PacketBuilder.Build(DateTime.Now,
                        new EthernetLayer
                            {
                                Source = new MacAddress("11:22:33:44:55:66"),
                                Destination = new MacAddress("11:22:33:44:55:67"),
                            },
                        new IpV4Layer
                            {
                                Source = new IpV4Address("1.2.3.4"),
                                Destination = new IpV4Address("1.2.3.5"),
                                Ttl = 64,
                                Identification = 100,
                            },
                        new PayloadLayer
                            {
                                Data = new Datagram(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4})
                            });
```

Comment: THANKs , I will try it ... and should useful for IP spoofing

Comment: Hi guy. can you give me an example of HttpWebRequest in C# with Pcap.Net?