# Create HTTP packet

Tags: http, packet, pcap.net

I would like create HTTP packet with random IP source.

Apparently, Pcap.net does it. 
I asked here : http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=227725, but I still have not figured out how to do it.

Anybody to help me to write code ?

I'm ready to do it in other langage than C#.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[IP address spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) is the term you are looking for.

An example of doing this with C# can be found here:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/razan/archive/2009/09/25/ip-address-spoofing-in-c-using-p-invoke.aspx

or this similar question may help you:

- [IP address spoofing using SharpPcap on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857223/making-ip-address-spoofing-using-sharp-pcap-on-c)

Comment: Yeah, before posting, I've been searching for long time and I found this two examples. The first, doesn't work, second, it's not HTTP packet. I need someone to help me to write code exactely