# c# send TCP packet without TCP handshake

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I am attempting to interop with a custom hardware device.

It requires the first TCP packet to contain a data payload

I tried to achieve this using TcpClient in System.Net.Sockets

```
   TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
   tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.1.11", 1500);
   Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
   byte[] ba = messagestr.StringToByteArray();                   
   stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
```

However wireshark shows that this code sends a number of TCP/IP packets to establish a connection and the data packet (containing messagestr) is the 4-5th packet.

How can I make C# send the data in the FIRST TCP packet?

Comment: If you don't want TCP to establish a connection, are you sure that your requirement is to create a TCP socket? Don't you need a raw socket?

Comment: wiresharking the *correct* packets I am trying to imitate shows them to be well formed TCP packets (though just 1 sent / 1 received)

Comment: If that really is the protocol that the hardware device implements, I suspect the creators to have been high on something. How does the SYN/ACK/sequence flow work then? Anyway check [TCP/IP Raw Sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx), [How do you get raw TCP packet in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034870/how-do-you-get-raw-tcp-packet-in-c), [Send TCP packet in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399473/send-tcp-packet-in-c-sharp).

Comment: "I suspect the creators to have been high on something" yes I fully agree(!) this is a RS232 protocol embedded into TCP packets :(

Comment: there is an ACK packet sent in response to the command (which is the first packet)

Comment: If you want to send hand-crafted TCP packets you need to use the WinPcap library. There are Pcap wrappers for C# like SharpPcap available.

Comment: Thank you, use of the winpcap driver was the key solution for us

Answer (score 3):

Use UDP to send only one packed without establishing a session. You are literally asking TCP not to be TCP.

Comment: wiresharking the correct packets I am trying to imitate shows them to be well formed TCP packets (though just 1 sent / 1 received) ... should I therefore be trying to create a TCP packet using the UDP protocol?