# Specify Custom IP in HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, ip, spoofing

is it possible to change orginating IP in HTTPWebRequest C# and provide any Custom/fake IP?

Comment: I am looking for some simple code example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the following Libraries

- [PCap.NET](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) Referenced from [IP address spoofing using PCap.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2857274/1012641)
- [sharppcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/) Referenced from [C# How to spoof IP address for WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7959380/1012641)

Comment: Do you have any code example fulfilling the requirement through these libraries ?