# Changing ip address before sending form

Tags: c#, forms, ip, send

I am looking for a solution for this problem:

I want to write a program in C# for sending some data to a website using an insert of some data into a form. But I want to change the IP address before sending each set of data.

I mean I want to fake the IP addresses, it is for testing purpose and I want to test large amount of request to my website.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here I guess;
[IP address spoofing using SharpPcap on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857223/ip-address-spoofing-using-sharppcap-on-c-sharp)

Download the library and add it to the References of your project, and then take a look at the sample provided in the answer, which is in the link above.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I download and setup the library, but I don't now how to send data using new Ip address. Could you help me ??

Comment: Read the sample provided in the link.